# Does react-native view not able to scroll without ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scrollview

This is the tutorial's link(https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6) from where I'm learning react-native.
Everything is working fine except the view is not scrolling

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
 import { List, ListItem } from "react-native-elements";

 type Props = {}
 export default class FlatListDemo extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: false,
        data: [],
        page: 1,
        seed: 1,
        error: null,
        refreshing: false,
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
}

makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const { page, seed } = this.state;
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`;
    this.setState({
        loading: true
    });

    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
                error: res.error || null,
                loading: false,
                refreshing: false
            })
        })
        .catch(error =>
            this.setState({
                error,
                loading: false
            })
        )
};
renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                height: 1,
                width: "86%",
                backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
                marginLeft: "14%"
            }}
        >
        </View>
    )
};



render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <ListItem
                    roundAvatar
                    title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
                    subtitle={item.email}
                    avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
                    containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
                />
            )}

            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
            onEndReachedThreshold={50}
        />        )
}}
```

**Is it compulsory to use ScrollView to make able to  scroll react-native view or we can do it 
 using any CSS or something else**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to run this code in this given link: https://snack.expo.io/rkOsCaiD7 to find for a solution what I found was scroll view was working fine with the above code. Just try to reload and run it in react native by which I feel it might resolve your issue.

Comment: i don't know what is the issue. i'm just importing Flatlist in my App.js main file and rendring here. but it's not able to scroll.

Comment: Inside your render() do as <List> entire code inside FlatList </List>
........Move the previous code between <List></List> tags

Comment: For reference see the render method here: https://snack.expo.io/BJvDCknv7